# How can I achieve Null-safety when calling a method written in Java from Kotlin, which throws an exception?

Tags: java, exception, kotlin

I am trying to rewrite a class with Kotlin in a Java product.
Our Java product has custom exceptions written like this:

```java
public class AppError {
    public static void exit(int res_code) {
        throw new AppException(res_code);
    }
    ...
}

public class AppException extends RuntimeException {
    private int res_code = CommonResCode.ERROR;

    public AppException() { super(); }

    public AppException(int res_code) {
        super();
        this.res_code = res_code;
    }
}
```

So in the existing code, there are codes like:

```java
int point = null;
point = someMap.get("foo")
if (point == null) {
    AppError.exit(THE_GIVEN_PARAMETER_IS_INVALID_CODE)
}
```

I want to rewrite this code with something like the Kotlin's

```
val point: Int = someMap.getOrElse("foo", { AppError.exit(...) })
// or
val point: Int = someMap["foo"] ?: AppError.exit(...)
```

But since the `exit` method is seen as returning `Unit`, Kotlin says that point is both `Int` and `Unit` and suggests me to define `point` as `Any`.
What can I do to avoid this? (other than doing the same as the Java code?)

#### Edit

Since the code logically always throws an exception, I thought casting may be the simple way:

```
val point: Int = someMap.getOrElse("foo", { AppError.exit(...) }) as Int
```

Is this correct? Or should I avoid doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the method is returning `void` (the `Unit` in Kotlin). Or rather, the method is never returning "normally" at all. It never finishes, because it always throws an exception.

AFAIK, there's nothing built-in which allows the use of custom exceptions. You could however create a new helper method similar to Java's [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-) or Kotlin's `!!` ([sure operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)):

```java
static <T> T requireOrThrow(final T value, final Supplier<Throwable> exceptionSupplier) {
    // be aware of boxing of primitive types
    if (value == null) throw exceptionSupplier.get();
    return value;
}
```

This can then be used from your Java …

```
int point = requireOrThrow(someMap.get("foo"), () -> new AppException(THE_GIVEN_PARAMETER_IS_INVALID_CODE));
```

… and Kotlin code, which should simplify both

```
val point: Int = requireOrThrow(someMap["foo"], { AppException(THE_GIVEN_PARAMETER_IS_INVALID_CODE) });
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider. Thanks! Should've made sure I wasn't still half asleep when I wrote that answer :) corrected.

Comment: I don't want to directly create `AppException` here, since it will be confusing to not use `AppError.exit`, andalso `AppError` has many kinds of constructors which all redirects to `AppEcception`. :(

Comment: In that case, you might be able to write your lambda in Kotline as: `{ AppError.exit(…); return 0 }` (or define a method with `int`/`T` return type), even though that might be confusing. The `0` will never be used anywhere. Static code analysis might warn you about unreachable code.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can write `val point: Int = someMap["foo"] ?: error(ERROR_MESSAGE)` because [`error`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/error.html?source=post_page---------------------------) function returns [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type).

So to make `val point: Int = someMap["foo"] ?: AppError.exit(...)` compile, you should make `AppError.exit(...)` return [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type).

Unfortunately, only Kotlin functions can return [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type), but there are still a few solutions to your problem:

**1**. Make `AppError.exit(...)` return `JNothing`:

```
public class AppError {
    public static JNothing exit(int res_code) {
        throw new AppException(res_code);
    }
}
```

Where `JNothing` is:

```
public final class JNothing {
    private JNothing() {}
}
```

`JNothing` to `Nothing` converter:

```
operator fun JNothing.invoke(): Nothing {
    error("Illegal JNothing instance was created [$this]")
}
```

Use case:

```
val point: Int = someMap["foo"] ?: AppError.exit(code)()
```

**2**. Create `KAppError.exit()` wrapper of `AppError.exit()` which returns `Nothing`:

```
object KAppError {
    fun exit(res_code: Int): Nothing = mustThrow {
        AppError.exit(res_code)
    }
}
```

Where `mustThrow` is:

```
@PublishedApi
internal const val EXCEPTION_HAS_NOT_BEEN_THROWN = "Exception was expected, but it hasn't been thrown!"

inline fun mustThrow(block: () -> Unit): Nothing {
    block()
    error(EXCEPTION_HAS_NOT_BEEN_THROWN)
}
```

Use cases:

```
val point: Int = someMap["foo"] ?: KAppError.exit(code)
val point1: Int = someMap["foo"] ?: mustThrow { AppError.exit(code) }
```

**3**. Make `AppError.exit()` return whatever is required:

```
public class AppError {
    public static <Nothing> Nothing exit(int res_code) {
        throw new AppException(res_code);
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
val point: Int = someMap["foo"] ?: AppError.exit(code)
```

**4**. Make `AppError.exit()` return exception instead of throwing it:

```
public class AppError {
    public static AppException exit(int res_code) {
        return new AppException(res_code);
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
val point: Int = someMap["foo"] ?: throw AppError.exit(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper method in Kotlin which returns `Nothing` to indicate it never returns:

```
object AppErrorK {
    fun exit(res_code: Int): Nothing {
        AppError.exit(res_code)
        // will never actually be reached, but makes Kotlin accept the correct return type
        throw Exception()
    }
}
```

Then things like

```
someMap["foo"] ?: AppErrorK.exit(...)
```

will work.